# Does .NET Core work with the NUnit console runner?

Tags: .net-core, nunit

I have a very simple test!

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(false);
}
```

When I try to run this with nunit3-console.exe I get the following error.

> NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException : The NUnit 3 driver encountered an
>   error while executing reflected code.   ---->
>   System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast transparent proxy to type
>   'System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler'.
>   --NUnitEngineException

I am running .NET Core 2.1, with *NUnit Console Runner 3.9* and *NUnit test adapter 3.1*. I did do a Google search and got conflicting answers. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are supposed to run `dotnet test`.

Comment: Yeah that is my next option, working that angle now. Is that your answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I reached out to the NUnit community and got this answer: *[Does NUnit Console work with .NET Core? #487](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/487)*

NUnit Console is compiled using the full .NET Framework and does not currently support .NET Core. To run .NET Core tests from the command line, you need to use `dotnet test`. For information on how to do this, see *[.NET Core and .NET Standard](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard)* (NUnit wiki).

We are looking at creating a .NET Core based console runner, but it is still in the planning stages.

Comment: It also says (4 days later) *"...you don't need to wait for a console runner from us. You can use `dotnet test` on the command line now with NUnit."*

Comment: Mid 2020: the main one (2018-10-05), *[Create .NET Core Console Runner #475](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/475)*, is still open.

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.13, NUnit.Console appears to support non .NET Framework tests, i.e. .NET Core, .NET 6, etc.

See https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases/tag/3.13

3.16.3 supports .NET 8.0 (https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases/tag/3.16.3).

Answer (score -1):

The recent release of NUnit 3.11 notes on the [releases page](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/releases) that:

> PlatformAttribute is available on .NET Standard 2.0 and now detects .NET Core

Try using NUnit 3.11.

I also found [this page](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard) in the NUnit documentation that talks about .NET Standard and .NET Core support. A cursory reading seems to me to suggest it is supported.

**UPDATE**

With dotnet core [Coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet) is your friend.  Also see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows).

I have moved on to the Cloud and Azure DevOps.  Yes, it is just TFS with a lot of lipstick but it is the Cloud.  (Psst: GitHub Actions is the future imo).

Here is my Unit Test task (in a yaml pipeline) that runs my NUnit test suite.  Essentially it is executing `dotnet test`, with which Coverlet is fully integrated.

```
# UnitTests
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Unit Tests'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(APEX_SOLUTION)'
    arguments: '--no-restore -c $(BUILD_CONFIGURATION) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Agent.TempDirectory)/ /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover /p:Threshold=50 /p:ThresholdType=branch /p:ThresholdStat=Average /p:Exclude="[DevOpsOnboarding.Views]*"'
    testRunTitle: 'Unit Tests $(Build.DefinitionName) - $(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Coverlet also allows you to produce OpenCover output in one step. After this task I can run ReportGenerator.

Should be straightforward to convert to a Jenkins Batch Step.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. I did get Xunit to work with it, and of course dotnet test, but only NUnit it installed on my Jenkins testing virtuals (I am going to request that be changed)

Comment: Let me see if that is for the CONSOLE runner/

Comment: I have just tried with 3.11.1 (March 2020) and I get the same error.

Comment: I just tried with 3.12.0 (November  2020) and I get the same error.