# How to pass parameters to the dotnet test command while using NUnit or XUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, nunit, xunit

I'm developing some end-to-end tests using C# with .NET Core, Selenium and NUnit.
Now i want to write a login testcase. My tests are started from console simply by using the `dotnet test` command.

I simply want to pass username and password to this command and get them in my tests. **I can not use NUnit-Console since it doesn't support .NET Core at the moment**.

Whats the suggested way to solve this problem? I would prefer to not store the settings in a file but to directly input them into the console.

Comment: As of 3.13+, the nunit console runner supports .NET Core (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76630719/13893216)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to avoid a runsettings file, you can use this workaround. One of the recommended ways of passing parameters, is through environment variables. So in your C# nunit (or xunit) file, you can do something like:

```
// in mytest.cs
var user = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TestUser");
var password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TestPassword");
var url = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TestUrl");
```

If you do not want to definitively set your environment variables, remember you can always set them temporarily for just your session process. One way of doing this, is by creating a simple cmd file

```
#launchtests.cmd
setlocal
set TestUser='pete001'
set TestPassword='secret'
set TestUrl='http://testserver.local/login'
dotnet test mytest.csproj
```

And now the fun part. You can parameterize every aspect of this. So you can change it to:

```
#run wity launchtests.cmd pete001 secret 'http://testserver.local/login'
setlocal
set TestUser=%1
set TestPassword=%2
set TestUrl=%3
dotnet test mytest.csproj
```

Or if you want to launch the test from an Azure DevOps (fka VSTS or TFS) pipeline, you can simply use the $(...) notation to inline variables, even if they're marked secret and/or come from Azure KeyVault.

```
#In Azure DevOps, variables not marked as secret are already added to the environment
set TestPassword=$(TestPassword)
dotnet test $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyCompany.MyProduct.UITests\MyTest.csproj --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect "Code Coverage" --logger trx --results-directory $(Agent.TempDirectory)
```

[image: run Azure DevOps command task]

Comment: Remember to use lowercase "set" on Ubuntu

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, the only way to pass settings from `dotnet test` into NUnit is to use a `.runsettings` file. There's no way for NUnit to create custom command line arguments for the `dotnet test` tool - although we'd love there to be!

Take a look at the sample `.runsettings` file [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/blob/8a9b8a38b7f808a4a78598542ddaf557950c6790/demo/demo.runsettings). The specific bit you'll need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Parameters used by tests at runtime -->
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" />
    <Parameter name="webAppUserName" value="Admin" />
    <Parameter name="webAppPassword" value="Password" />
  </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

You should just be able to then pass this file into `dotnet test` with the `-s` flag.

```
dotnet test myProj.csproj -s mySettings.runsettings
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll keep it like this for the moment. All other pages i read also mentioned that its not currently possible. However, it may be possible in xUnit, maybe its worth to have a look at this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 10):

This documentation suggests that it should now be possible to pass in arguments on the command line, instead of within a runsettings file.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/RunSettingsArguments.md

```sh
dotnet test -- MSTest.MapInconclusiveToFailed=True MSTest.DeploymentEnabled=False
```

Note the space after `--` .

**Edit 1**

What worked for me was a combination of adding a runsettings file, and then overriding the param I wanted to, using this syntax:

`dotnet test -- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"myParam\", value=\"value\")`

Comment: HI, When I execute the cmd file in a powershell in the folder location, getting below error : Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-TEST does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Comment: From https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/main/docs/RunSettingsArguments.md

# cmd
dotnet test  -- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"myParam\", value=\"value\")

# powershell
dotnet test --%  -- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"myParam\", value=\"value\") 

# bash
dotnet test -- TestRunParameters.Parameter\(name=\"myParam\",\ value=\"value\"\)

Answer (score 3):

You can also pass environment variables to `dotnet test` via the `-e`/`--environment` parameter.

```
dotnet test TestProject.csproj --environment USERNAME="Bob" --environment PASSWORD="password"
```

After that you can retrieve those values using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` like mentioned in the other answers.

```cs
var username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
var password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PASSWORD");
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#synopsis

Answer (score -1):

we can directly pass environment variables through
for example: **param1=vale param2=value dotnet test**
Get value in c#:

```
 var user = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("param1");
```